# Set cell contents to sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

Simple question for you experts out there.

Trying to figure out how to have cell A1 = sheetname.

I tried the following but got a compile error

```
y = Sheetname()

Range(A1) = y
```

Comment: Something like this? `MySheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = ActiveSheet.Name`

If you want it for every sheet, then

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Range("A1") = ws.Name
Next
```